# Automatically parsing language strings from blade files

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I would like to parse out language strings from blade files (`{{ __('some phrase') }}`) and store them automatically in language files. I did try a plugin related to this which worked alright but did not allow functions to be ran. I created the below regex.

```
{                              // Opening curly brace
    (?:\s+?)?                  // Optional spacing
    {                          // Opening curly brace
        (?:\s+?)?              // Optional spacing
        (?:.+?)?               // Optional function
            __\(               // Begin translation function
                (?:\s+?)?      // Optional spacing
                    (?:'|\")   // Single or double quote

                        (.+?)  // Actual string to capture

                    (?:'|\")   // Single or double quote
                (?:\s+?)?      // Optional spacing
            (?:\)|,)           // End translation function, basically
        (?:.+?)?               // Ending optional function
        (?:\s+?)?              // Optional spacing
    }                          // Ending curly brace
    (?:\s+?)?                  // Optional spacing
}                              // Ending curly brace
```

```
"/{(?:\s+?)?{(?:\s+?)?(?:.+?)?__\((?:\s+?)?(?:'|\")(.+?)(?:'|\")(?:\s+?)?(?:\)|,)(?:.+?)?(?:\s+?)?}(?:\s+?)?}/"
```

I know this isn't perfect, how can I improve this further to catch some edge cases better, such as some ending string breaking the capture in the middle?

Comment: You should probably try to have a look i the plugin you tried and see how they match everything. Maybe they also covered eventual edge cases ( not sure what those would be )

Comment: They did not, which is why I embarked on rolling my own. Thank you for the comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did something like this using [this github repo](https://github.com/kkomelin/laravel-translatable-string-exporter) as the base:

The only thing I needed from here was the actual parsing regex and logic which can be found in [this file](https://github.com/kkomelin/laravel-translatable-string-exporter/blob/master/src/Core/CodeParser.php)

To keep it simple, what they did was parse for and match the the actual possible functions used for displaying translated strings: `__`, `_t`, `@lang`. By doing this, it no longer needs to search for and match the curly braces because that could be a pain in case you are using:

1. filters: `{{ __('whatever') | ucfirst }}`
2. conditional rendering: `{{ $title ?? __('Whatever') }}`

And there are many other cases that would make your regex crazy.

By matching the functions only, the pattern is pretty simple:

`/(__|_t|@lang)\(\h*[\'"](.+)[\'"]\h*[\),]/U`

[Here is a Regex101 example showcasing the cases you are looking for](https://regex101.com/r/Eo4brY/2)

Comment: Good point on the unnecessary curly brace matching I was doing. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it works :)

Comment: It does. Your regex is far more on point than what I threw at the wall. Cheers, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that you tried, could also be written as

```
{\s*{.*?__\(\s*['"](.+?)['"]\s*[,)].*?}\s*}
```

A few notes

- `(?:\s+?)?` can be written as `\s*?`
- `(?:'|\")`  can be written using a character class as `['"]`
- `(?:.+?)?` can be written as `.*?`
- `(?:\)|,)` can be written as `[),]`

To prevent for example the string to break on a single or double quote in the capture group, you could use 2 negated character classes with an alternation matching from opening till closing single or double quotes.

```
{\s*{.*?__\(\s*("[^"]*"|'[^']*')\s*[,)].*?}\s*}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5WAgH9/1)

- `{\s*{` Match `{{` with optional whitespace char in between
- `.*?__` Match as least as possible chars, then match `__`
- `\(\s*` Match `(` and optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `"[^"]*"` Match from an opening `"` till closing `"`
  - `|` Or
  - `'[^']*'` Match from an opening `'` till closing `'`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s*[,)]` Match optional whitespace chars and either `,` or `)`
- `.*?` Match as least as possible chars
- `}\s*}` Match `}}` with optional whitespace chars in between

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5WAgH9/1/)

---

**Note** that `.*?` can match any character except a newline. For the example data, you can replace those 2 occurrences with `\s*` matching optional whitespace chars instead.

```
{\s*{\s*__\(\s*("[^"]*"|'[^']*')\s*[,)]\s*}\s*}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aCpPXs/1)